# Ember.js + Leaflet + rails ( creating a rails app with a Javascript MVC and opens source maps)

Tags: ember.js, javascript, leaflet

Im a rails newbie (6 months with a few apps). Im also a Javascript newbie. I taught myself rails now Im teaching myself a Javascript framework. I've analyzed all the frameworks and have settled on learning "ember.js".

I need to also use a maps library in my app. I have used Google maps in the past but this is not an option anymore because of Google's liscencing and other issues.

So Ive decided to go with leaflet.

Now from a newbie's perspective, I was curious to see if there are any conflicts between the leaflet and ember.js libraries. Will they play nice with each other?

before I invest time and energy are there any caveats I should be aware of when combining the two. Would another Javascript MVC library play better?

Are there any links tutorials with rails, ember and leaflet available? (I googled the term and couldn't find any)

Any help to get me started would be awesome and really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick browse through the leaflet source suggests that it shouldn't have any problems with ember.js Both frameworks are most likely written in a [closure](http://thatsobscene.wordpress.com/2010/03/13/javascript-closures-a-fairly-simple-explanation-of/) to solve problems of incompatibility. Seeing as they dont do the same thing (ie. like using backbone with ember) I would say you are fine.

In terms of helping you get off the ground, I would suggest you look though some tutorials on using ember with rails. A quick [google search](https://www.google.ca/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=emberjs%20and%20rails) reveals plenty of walkthroughs

Comment: I can confirm this. We are using ember.js and leaflet in the same web application - works just fine.

Comment: @Asbjørn could you perhaps give me the link for some tutorial code samples. Thanks

Comment: @banditKing Sorry, I am not aware of any tutorials that include both leaflet and ember. Both are new frameworks, and not really related, so I guess that is why examples/tutorials are hard to find. If you encounter any specific problems combining the two, just ask here on stack overflow, and I will see if I can help.

Comment: I would like to add that it depends on the level of integration you need. I'm trying to use ember and leaflet and I'm having a hard time creating, for instance, a `zoomLevel` property that represents leaflet's zoom itself. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657579/how-to-create-an-ember-property-dependent-on-a-normal-variable-function-or-logi

Maybe you could help? Thanks.