# How to create an ember property dependent on a normal variable, function or logic?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, leaflet

### The problem

I'm working on a leaflet view for emberjs, and I'm having some problems. Leaflet is an external library and somewhat irrelevant to the question, but just know that it is a mapping library.

Consider a simple property like zoom level. Leaflet map instances have a zoom level accessible through `map.getZoom()` and assignable through `map.setZoom(zoomLevel)`. Also, users can interact with the map, and change its zoom level. Leaflet allows us to [register a callback](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-events) when the zoom changes.

I would like my "Ember-Leaflet" View to have a `zoomLevel` ember property. This way I can benefit from the ember object model (bind `zoomLevel` to a template or to another value, for example), and we're doing it "the ember way".

### Base solution

What I currently have is a subclass of Ember.View, with a zoomLevel property. On `didInsertElement` I create the Leaflet map instance. The code is commented and should be self-explanatory.

```
App.Leaflet = Ember.View.extend({
    classNames : ['ember-leaflet'],

    //default zoom level
    zoomLevel : 13,
    didInsertElement : function() {
        var self = this;
        var zoomLevel = this.get('zoomLevel');

        // create map instance
        var map = L.map(this.$().get(0)).setView(center, zoomLevel);

        // configure map instance...

        // Event listeners
        map.on('zoomend', function(e) {
            self.set('zoomLevel', e.target.getZoom());
        });

        // save map instance
        this.set('map', map);
    }
});
```

### Checklist

To make this question more "answerable", I think that a solution to this problem should fulfill the following requirements:

1. When the property `zoomLevel` is changed, the map should change its zoom level accordingly (using `map.setZoom(zoomLevel)`)
2. When the user interactively changes the zoom on the map, the `zoomLevel` property should be changed (probably using leaflet map's `zoomend` event callback)

Notice that we have here a kind of "circular dependency", i.e *"Do something (setZoom on map) when `zoomLevel` changes"* and *"when something happens (user changes zoom), change `zoomLevel`"*. I would like a solution that could avoid this circular observer dependencies. Ember's [notifyPropertyChange](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Observable.html#method_notifyPropertyChange) could be a solution.

This seemed like an ideal task for [Ember's computed properties](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/), but I didn't know what to put in the dependent properties string. `zoomLevel` is basically a property that is dependent on something that isn't an ember property.

---

### Update

My first attempt was to use an observer to set the zoom on leaflet and to bind an event on leaflet `zoomend` to set the `zoomLevel` on my view.

Problem: When I set zoomLevel on the zoomend leaflet event, I'm automatically triggering again my observer. Did I make myself clear?

So, this sequence of events happen:

1. change `zoomLevel` on interactive map
2. leaflet fires `zoomend` event
3. `zoomend` event callback sets ember `zoomLevel`
4. observer runs
5. unecessarily calls `setZoom` on leaflet

This is not efficient, but I wouldn't mind if it worked.
The problem is that when the user changes zoom multiple times very quickly (a simple long scroll on map) the observer is called multiple times, [confusing leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671949/why-does-calling-leaflets-setzoom-twice-results-on-the-second-being-ignored).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I've did it.

I used a computed property and an auxiliary property.

```
App.Leaflet = Ember.View.extend({
    classNames : ['ember-leaflet'],

    //default zoom level
    zoomLevelValue : 13,
    zoomLevel : function(key, value){
        // getter
        if (arguments.length === 1) {
            var zoomLevel = this.get('zoomLevelValue');
            return zoomLevel;
        // setter  
        } else{
            var map = this.get('map');

            this.set('zoomLevelValue', value);
            map.setZoom(value);

            return value;
        }
    }.property('zoomLevelValue'),

    didInsertElement : function() {
        var self = this;
        var zoomLevel = this.get('zoomLevel');

        var map = L.map(this.$().get(0)).setView(center, zoomLevel);

        // configure map instance...

        // Event listeners
        map.on('zoomend', function(e) {
            console.log('zoomend', 'Setting zoomLevel '+e.target.getZoom());
            self.set('zoomLevelValue', e.target.getZoom());
        });

        // save map instance
        this.set('map', map);

    }
});
```

Basically, there are two scenarios:

1. zoomLevel was changed programatically -> we update the zoom on the map
2. zoomLevel was changed on the map -> we set on the auxiliary property, and the computer property observers will also get notified, and we didn't set the zoom level on the map again

However I have a new problem, but I think it is leaflet related. When I call `setZoom` when another zoom animation on course, this setZoom is ignored.
For example, executing:

```
map.setZoom(1);
map.setZoom(12);
```

ends up in the `1` zoom level.

Maybe a leaflet related SO question can help.

Comment: This ended up in a project called Ember-Leaflet: http://miguelcobain.github.io/ember-leaflet/

Contributions are welcome!

Comment: Your link is broken. Here's the correct one: [Ember-Leaflet](http://miguelcobain.github.io/ember-leaflet-2/). Great work by the way!

Comment: Thanks!
That project is not maintained anymore. Me and some other developers started another one here: https://github.com/gabesmed/ember-leaflet

It is much more "ember way", more structured, with tests, etc. I'm sure it will suit better your needs. :)

Answer (score 1):

To get from zoomLevel in ember to setZoom you can use an observer.

To go the other way you may have to bind an event to zoomChange on the leaflet

Comment: Yes, that was my first attempt. Problem: When I set `zoomLevel` on the `zoomend` leaflet event, I'm automatically triggering again my observer. Did I make myself clear?

Answer (score 1):

With little different strategy, I made zoomLevel a property and observes it from a function, and only set the zoom on the map if the actual value of the property is different from the actual zoom.
See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5As2z/30/
I passed the logic to a controller, the view set the map when inserted in document

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
//default zoom level
zoomLevel: 13,
map: null,
zoomLevelChanged: function () {
    var zoomLevel = this.get('zoomLevel');
    var map = this.get('map');
    //Control not changing the zoom of the map if it is yet at the value
    if (zoomLevel != map.getZoom()) {
        map.setZoom(zoomLevel);
    }
}.observes('zoomLevel')});

App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
templateName: 'application',
didInsertElement: function () {
    var center = [41.3823000, 2.1825000];
    var controller = this.get('controller');
    var zoomLevel = controller.get('zoomLevel');
    var map = L.map('map').setView(center, zoomLevel);
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);
    // configure map instance...

    // Event listeners
    map.on('zoomend', function (e) {
        console.log('zoomend', 'Setting zoomLevel ' + e.target.getZoom());
        controller.set('zoomLevel', e.target.getZoom());
    });

    // save map instance
    this.controller.set('map', map);
}});
```

html

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <h1> Leaflet map ember example </h1>
    {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="zoomLevel"}}
    <div id="map"></div >
</script>
```