# Why does calling leaflet's setZoom twice results on the second being ignored?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

To reproduce this problem, you can go to http://leafletjs.com/ and in the javascript console, write the following:

```
> map.getZoom()
15
> map.setZoom(10);map.setZoom(1);
Object
> map.getZoom()
10
```

I was expecting the final getZoom to return `1`. Why does this happen?
The problem may be related with the zoom animation. If a setZoom is called before the animation ends, it gets ignored.

I'm integrating leaflet with emberjs and wanted to allow zoom changes by external changes. If the user changes zoom quickly, the effect isn't the desired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`L.Map.setZoom`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/map/Map.js#L52) called [`L.Map.setView`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/map/anim/Map.PanAnimation.js#L23) that called [`L.Map._animateZoomIfClose`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/map/anim/Map.ZoomAnimation.js#L29).
If `map._animatingZoom` is true then any zoom will stop. `map._animatingZoom` work like look for zoom animation:

1. Check at [`L.Map._animateZoomIfClose`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/map/anim/Map.ZoomAnimation.js#L29) if `true` stop zoom else call [`L.Map._animateZoom`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/map/anim/Map.ZoomAnimation.js#L50).
2. Set to `true` at [`L.Map._animateZoom`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/map/anim/Map.ZoomAnimation.js#L50) and start css transition.
3. Set to `false` at [`L.Map._onZoomTransitionEnd`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/map/anim/Map.ZoomAnimation.js#L74) on css transition end.

Why it's as is? I think because it's difficult break css transition work.

So if you will disable any css transform and transition your code must work right. You also can add own extension: if `map._animatingZoom === true` then put your action to array, when `map._catchTransitionEnd` called process this and shift your action from array and process:

```
if (L.DomUtil.TRANSITION) {
    L.Map.addInitHook(function () {
        L.DomEvent.on(this._mapPane, L.DomUtil.TRANSITION_END, function () {
            var zoom = this._zoomActions.shift();
            if (zoom !== undefined) {
                this.setZoom(zoom);
            }
        }, this);
    });
}

L.Map.include(!L.DomUtil.TRANSITION ? {} : {
    _zoomActions: [],
    queueZoom: function (zoom) {
        if (map._animatingZoom) {
            this._zoomActions.push(zoom);
        } else {
            this.setZoom(zoom);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That was very enlightening.

Comment: It's odd that this doesn't happen with `panTo`. Zoom is a special case, probably because it uses CSS3 transitions?
Do you know any other Leaflet properties that might require the kind of logic you posted?
Thanks!

Comment: Look like pan doesn't have any animation lock: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/map/anim/Map.PanAnimation.js#L7, but `pubBy` also use css transitions. For maps exist only two moved parts: zoom and movement. Look where used map anamations: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/tree/master/src/map/anim.