# Mapbox.js set map default zoom option

Tags: javascript, zooming, mapbox

I have a mapbox.js map but the parameter `zoom` doesn't seem to be doing anything
and I can't figure it out in the documentation. whatever I set `zoom` to the zoom level always defaults to my project zoom level Here is the code:

```
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.6.1/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.6.1/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />

$(document).ready(function() {
        var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'nhaines.hek4pklk', {
            zoom: 1
        });

        // disable drag and zoom handlers
        map.dragging.disable();
        map.touchZoom.disable();
        map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
        map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
        // disable tap handler, if present.
        if (map.tap) map.tap.disable();
    });
```

Comment: You ever figure this out? I'm stuck with this too. Looking at the source, it should work fine. I'm waiting to hear back from their dev. team.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not. Great application but the docs were tough for me. The client project fell through too so I didn't put much more time into it. Let me know though if they get back, I want to use Mapbox in for future projects.

Answer (score 2):

It took me a lot of digging around but I figured this out on my own. The dev's didn't respond yet. We were going about this all wrong. Here's what to do:

First, create the MapBox object, but set `zoomAnimation` to false. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671949/why-does-calling-leaflets-setzoom-twice-results-on-the-second-being-ignored) helped me realize that trying to `setZoom` while a CSS3 animation was in progress wouldn't ever work because it's tough to break out of. At least that's what I think is going on. Setting `zoomAnimation` to `true` allows the map to animate in and bypasses any custom zoom levels, so clearly this is very important.

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'username.map_id', {
    zoomAnimation: false
});
```

Next, create a polygon layer and add to map from map's geojson. You find this within your MapBox projects > info tab. (In my case this geojson happens to contain the lat/lng coords of a polygon but your case may be different. `featureLayer()` should still add the geojson either way.)

```
var polygonLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().loadURL('http://your/maps/geojson').addTo(map);
```

After polygon layer (or whatever your lat/lng coords are of) has been added to map

```
polygonLayer.on('ready', function() {
    // featureLayer.getBounds() returns the corners of the furthest-out markers,
    // and map.fitBounds() makes sure that the map contains these.
    map.fitBounds(polygonLayer.getBounds());

    map.setView(map.getCenter(), 10);
}
```

Apparently `fitBounds` satisfies the `map` requirements to allow `setView` to be called on it, since now you can just call the `map` object directly to get the center lat/lng.

I haven't tested this in simple cases - I adapted this code from mine which checks if an address's lat/lng coords fall within a polygon while iterating over a series of MapBox maps. It should get you going though. Hope it helps!